# How to effectively use debugger to study how clang builds AST

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, lldb, clang++

I am trying to study how clang builds AST for various functions and methods definitions using calls to `clang::Sema` methods and other related functions. For this I am using `lldb` debugger, But I am having difficulties in how to effectively set breakpoints. For instance, if I am debugging *hello.cpp* file with content,

```
void fn() {
  printf("Hello World!"); 
}

int main() {
  int a,b;
  fn();
}
```

and I am debugging it like this,

```
lldb clang
*set breakpoints here*
process launch -- *clang arguments obtained using clang++ hello.cpp -v*
```

How should I set breakpoints to obtain all function/method calls used to construct AST for `fn` definition. And is it possible to save all these functions in order to some other file? as it will be easier to study that way.